# JQuery wrong script order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery script, and it does not work in head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
            alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
            event.preventDefault();
        });
}
</script>
```

But if I put the code below the form it usually works.

I want to put it in a .js file. But does not work in the head tag, only if I include after the form.

It is possible to make this code work in head tag?

Comment: First of all, your script requires jQuery libraries, which in html must be included before your scipt, secondary I prefer to work with `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code */ });` instead of `$(window).load();`

Comment: `$(window).load(function() {}` will not run only when rendering the whole page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize jQuery like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
        alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle for troubleshooting?

Comment: Glad your sorted it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the form is not rendered before `.load` event is fired.

Check what window is, but you might want to write:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
            alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
            event.preventDefault();
        });
     });
</script>
```

Check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

If you don't use the `.ready` approach, it is going to execute the code, search for `#target` and find nothing, because the render has not passed the object that you are targeting so it is not able to find it

Comment: My mistake was to close the function, missed a `});`. And I was trying to solve for hours. --'

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $(document).on("submit", "#target", function(event) {
        alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```